# AngularJS: empty array when item is removed

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, web, firebase

I've made a quick angular app, where users can add entries and they are organized into groups, however I'm having trouble figuring out how to remove items belonging to a group when that group is removed.

```
$scope.removeGroup = function(groupname, myentries, entry, $index){
$scope.mygroups.$remove(groupname),
  $scope.myentries.$remove,
$scope.selectedgroup = null;
```

here is the full application: http://codepen.io/Zancrash/pen/NNVRWp?editors=1010

I tried to use `$scope.myentries.$remove($index)` however that just deleted the first item belonging to the group deleted instead of all of them.

Comment: You'd need to remove associated entries via a loop.

Comment: how would that be written?